# How refresh google+ api key in c#

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

The Google API key is for 24th . after this expire. so i need to refresh it in my project. so I've used the following code to refresh API key in WPF c#

```
  class refApiKey
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This example uses the discovery API to list all APIs in the discovery repository.
    /// https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using.
    /// <summary>
       [STAThread]
      public  static void main()
        {

            try
            {
                new refApiKey().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
                }
            }

        }
       string key;
        private async Task Run()
        {
            // Create the service.
            var service = new DiscoveryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    ApplicationName = "Discovery Sample",
                    ApiKey = "apikey",
                });

            // Run the request.

            var result = await service.Apis.List().ExecuteAsync();

            // Display the results.
            if (result.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryList.ItemsData api in result.Items)
                {
                    key=key+api.Id + " - " + api.Title;
                }
            }
            variebls.apikey = key;
        }
    }
```

But when you run this code, the class `ConfigurableMessageHandler` on line 313, `return response` to the hang out .Why does this happen?
what should i do ?

Comment: API keys don't expire can you try and explain what you are doing your code also uses directory api not the google+ api.

Answer (score 0):

A really [simple Basic API example in C# is here](http://gusclass.com/blog/2014/04/16/how-to-oauth-2-0-flows-using-the-google-net-api-client-libraries-1-7-in-c/). This project uses the [.NET client from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/).

```
PlusService plusService = new PlusService(
                new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = API_KEY
                });
Person me = plusService.People.Get(@"+GusClass").Execute();
```

As mentioned before, you do not need to refresh an API key.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.